# German special character did not showing correctly in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, utf-8

Currently I am working with word press plugin development , I have form contains some German special characters , but it does showing properly in the webpage

For eg : - when I put ä German letter , the page displaying  � type things.
 how it comes ??
I have tried `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, but it doesn't change anything  and also tried

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

But it' does change anything, still getting � type of character , anyone please help thank in advance ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some German special character you can't directly write that.

Please use &auml for for ä

For more details Refer the links

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-de.htm#codes